# Not able to reorder items inside "TokenizingTextBox" by dragging and drooping in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit, app.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="sample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:sample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="xlgrid">
    <controls:TokenizingTextBox Width="700" Height="400" CanReorderItems="True" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" SelectionMode="Single">
        
    </controls:TokenizingTextBox>
</Grid>
```

Not able to reorder items inside "TokenizingTextBox" by dragging and drooping in UWP